# Meaning of imaginary number

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

I'm a bit confused about the true meaning of imaginary number. It's my understanding that a complex number is a number of the form $a+ib$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. A pure imaginary number is a complex number where $a=0$. However, when they say that a number is an "imaginary number", without the "pure", what do they mean exactly?

Comment: There is no difference between "pure imaginary numbers" and "imaginary numbers".

Comment: You should generally avoid using the word "imaginary" since it suggests that complex numbers with $b≠0$ are less "real", in the ontological sense, than numbers which can be represented on a number line(elements of $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When people say "imaginary number" they should mean what you call a "pure imaginary number", i.e. one of the form $ib$ where $b$ is real. (However people are occasionally sloppy and say "imaginary" when all they mean is "complex".)

Comment: The usage is nowhere near consistent. One speaks of an “imaginary quadratic field”, even though only some of its elements are purely imaginary.